# Install imagick to azure

Tags: php, azure, imagick

I tried to install Image magick for php on azure web app.

I used the guideline - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/.

I tried to follow it step by step but it didn't work.

I got this error:

> Class 'Imagick' not found in ...

I used the .dll from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows

Comment: Are you getting errors? Please provide some more detail about what is wrong.

Comment: Class 'Imagick' not found in D:\home\site\wwwroot\index.php on line 5

Comment: in phpinfo() i dont have any information about imagick

Comment: This is likely better suited for serverfault, as it is not programming related but software administration/installation

Comment: May be its unpossible..

Comment: Improved spelling grammar and formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Please upload phpinfo.php file to azure website to test whether the imagick extension has been installed, like the following screenshot:
[image]

I have use a custom PHP runtime to install this extension successfully, the article you provide is a good resource, please have a look at this part: "How to: Use a custom PHP runtime", you need to pay attention to the following:

1) please download the no thread safe version at:  https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.1.2/windows, and also need to match the PHP version

2) If use your customer PHP runtime, please don't forget to change the extension dir path.

[image]

3) please copy the php_imagick.dll to the ext folder and other 8 dlls in the php folder

Comment: How did you install the library? Did you just copy the DLLs to the folder? I keep getting the error: "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Can you remimber what the php folder was? Hopefully not C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.3\bin ? because there, i get a permission denied in the kdu console.

Answer (score 0):

I found from lots of digging, articles and posts that not all imagick libraries are compatible for installation here. The dlls which worked for me on PHP 5.6 were from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.3.0rc2/php_imagick-3.3.0rc2-5.6-nts-vc11-x86.zip. I later wrote about it describing the exact steps which worked for me at http://techblog.saurabhkumar.com/2015/12/setting-up-imagemagick-for-php-on-azure.html