# Install imagick extension in Azure Web Service

Tags: php, azure, imagick

I'm facing with a problem on Azure Web Service that need for your help.
I'm installing a PHP website, that need to enable Imagick extension. I have searched on Azure Document and Stackoverflow for some solutions. But the problem is still not be solved.
Also, I tried some other solution but still the same result.
Some referenced sites:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-configure/
- [Install imagick to azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701041/install-imagick-to-azure)
- https://azureossd.github.io/2015/12/07/php-imagemagick-on-azure-web-apps/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bf834b84-278a-4601-b163-f2060c25d5b8/phpweb-apps-install-imagick-php-enstension-to-web-app?forum=opensourcedevwithazure
- ...(other sites that i cannot remember)...

Anyone please help me! Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: What is the error that you see? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You could try installing with Composer: https://www.obungi.com/2017/06/15/installing-imagick-php-extension-on-azure-web-service-with-composer/